# Running mpirun with srun on multiple nodes gives a different communicator

Tags: mpi, slurm

I am using the hello world example from [Here](http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-hello-world/), in which every process is printing its process name along with its MPI_COMM_WORLD rank id and communicator size.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Initialize the MPI environment
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    // Get the number of processes
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    // Get the rank of the process
    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

    // Get the name of the processor
    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    int name_len;
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);

    // Print off a hello world message
    printf("Hello world from processor %s, rank %d out of %d processors\n",
           processor_name, world_rank, world_size);

    // Finalize the MPI environment.
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

I am running this example in two different ways on slurm, once with srun and once with sbatch.

More precisely :

(1)

```
srun -N 2 -n 2 mpirun ./a.out
```

(2)

```
sbatch testsimple.job
```

With the file testsimple.job containing :

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -N 2
#SBATCH -n 2
mpirun ./a.out
```

The problem is that I do not understand the difference in the output, with configurations that are similar, from my understanding at least.

The outputs are :

(1)

```
Hello world from processor node1, rank 0 out of 2 processors
Hello world from processor node2, rank 1 out of 2 processors
Hello world from processor node2, rank 1 out of 2 processors
Hello world from processor node1, rank 0 out of 2 processors
```

(2)

```
Hello world from processor node1, rank 0 out of 2 processors
Hello world from processor node2, rank 1 out of 2 processors
```

Output (2) is as I expect, but not output (1) using srun.
Here srun seems to be precisely executing mpirun on each node and both runs are not whithin the same MPI application so the MPI_COMM_WORLD communicator is not the same on both nodes. Whereas sbatch manages to do that.

I do not think this is intended so my only guess is that there is something wrong with my understanding of slurm or with the way I use it.

I think that I need to use srun for my application because it has a low level option `--cpu_bind`, while sbatch do not have it.
I think I need to use this option to do [heterogeneous job allocation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/heterogeneous_jobs.html) manually,  having slurm version lower than 17.11, following [this](https://slurm.schedmd.com/mc_support.html#srun_lowlevelmc) guide.

My question are :

- Do you see an obvious mistake in my usage of slurm or my understanding of what both commands should do ? Or do you think it could be related to the slurm configuration (which I know nothing about and I am not the administrator) ?
- If the issue is not obvious, do you have another suggestion using sbatch for heterogeneous jobs ?

Thanks for reading and for any help you may provide !

Comment: If `pmi` support was built in your MPI library, then simply `srun ./a.out`

Answer (score 0):

Running `srun -N 2 -n 2 mpirun ./a.out` leads to Slurm allocating two tasks on two nodes, and getting each task to run `mpirun ./a.out`, resulting in four processes being created in the end.

You should only run `srun -N 2 -n 2 ./a.out`. If both Slurm and your MPI library are correctly configured, it should work ok.